# Loading a gallery image into an imageview on a dialog

Tags: android, android-dialog

I need to load a picture into an imageview that is on a custom dialog (a class that extends dialog).

1. A dialog is called within a class, extends dialog and let user choose to load a picture from gallery or take a picture from camera...so far so good!
2. Then startActivityForResult() is not part of Dialog object!
   and for getting the result
3. onActivityResult() also is not part of Dialog class!

Code:

```
    package ....;

    .....

    public class AnosLeitura extends Dialog {

        ...

        public void btnImageLogo_OnClick(View v) {
            edLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image);
            final String[] option = new String[] { "From camera", 
                                                   "From gallery" };
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                                           android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, option);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setTitle("Choice");
            builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (which == 0) { callCamera(); }
                    if (which == 1) { callGallery(); }
                }
            });
            final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }

        ....

        public void callGallery() {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
            intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
            intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);
            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

            //This is not possible!
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"),
                                              PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
        }

        // Neither this!
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
                return;

            switch (requestCode) {
                case CAMERA_REQUEST: 
                     Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                     if (extras != null) {
                          Bitmap yourImage = extras.getParcelable("data");
                          ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                          yourImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                          imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();
                          edLogo.setImageBitmap(yourImage); 
                     }
                     break;
                case PICK_FROM_GALLERY: 
                     Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();
                     if (extras2 != null) {
                          Bitmap yourImage = extras2.getParcelable("data");
                          ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                          yourImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                          imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();
                          edLogo.setImageBitmap(yourImage); 
                     }
                     break;
            }
     }

    ....

}
```

Does anyone know some solution?

Tks

Comment: Indeed startActivityForResult is not part of Dialog. But what does it matter here? As soon as the user clicks "from camera" or "from gallery" the dialog box closes. Or not? Is AnosLeitura  the 'custom dialog' you talked about? You want to grab a picture and put it in edLogo of AnosLeitura.

Comment: I think you better make an activity with a dialog theme. Then it looks like a dialog but startActivityForResul and onActivityResult are available and the Axctivity will not close when the user clicks an option.

Comment: No. It is not closing. Well it does but that is the not the main Dialog. So the main dialog is still there after the choice. But for the reest: those functions are not implemented for a Dialog.

Comment: Hi yes the dialog doesn't close! and yes AnosLeitura is the custom dialog!

Comment: The porpose is to input values to a database only after user confirm values entered.

Comment: ??? Does he confirm by choosing a picture??? Why don't you react on my suggestion to use an activity instead?

Comment: There are confirmation button! I had a activity... and it worked  fine. I changed the input data to a dialog because it makes more sense and logic.